# edit the UITextField.text property directly the UITextFieldDelegate will not fire

Tags: ios, delegates, uitextfield

If you edit the UITextField.text property directly the UITextFieldDelegate will not fire. Is there a proper way of using the UITextField with a custom input view? I created my own numberpad viewcontroller, and I can modify the UITextField.text but I can not get the cursor location if I don't receive events from UITextFieldDelegate.shouldChangeCharactersInRange.

Any idea on what's the proper way of using a custom input with UITextField?

Answer (score 0):

please make sure

```
yourTextField.delegate = self
```

this line in your implementation file

Comment: The `UITextFieldDelegate` will not fire with a custom `InputView`. Even when assigning the delegate to self.

Answer (score 0):

I also created a custom numpad for our application.  You're right that `shouldChangeCharactersInRange` doesn't respond to programmatic text changes (via setText).  We use the `UIControlEventEditingChanged` event on the text field:

```
[aField addTarget:self action:@selector(editingChanged:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventEditingChanged];
```

Unfortunately, there's [currently no way](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1885288/how-to-determine-the-cursor-position-of-a-uitextfield) to access the cursor position of a UITextField outside of shouldChangeCharactersInRange.  You can insert text at the cursor using [this pasting method](http://dev.ragfield.com/2009/09/insert-text-at-current-cursor-location.html).  As for a custom delete key, we are going with the "always delete the last character in the field" rule for now.